# Call Rest WCF service PUT method with parameter

Tags: wcf, rest

I have a RESTFUL WCF services PUT method with parameters and I have not been able to execute it with the proper parameter values.

```
OperationContract()

WebInvoke( Method:="PUT", UriTemplate:="/Fixit/{Id}")

Public Sub UpdateLocation(ByVal Id As String, ByVal location As Location)
End Sub
```

Location is a class and it has theses properties:

```
DataContract(Name:=MyLocation,Namespace="")


Public class Location

    DataMember(Order:=1)

Public Property Name As String

DataMember(Order:=2)

Public Property Address As String

End Class
```

I have tried using `WebRequest.create(uri)` and `WebResponse` but no sure how to pass in the Location class content.

I have tried JQUERY but the parameter values that were sent to the server were blanks

```
    $(function () {
       var Location = { "MyLocation": { "Name": "ABC", "Address": "123"} };
        $.ajax({
            type: "PUT",
            url: "http://localhost/Fixit/{Id}",
            data: JSON.stringify(Location),
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            processData:false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                alert("Failed: " + data.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

How do I consume this PUT method, passing data to the Location class?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I figured it out.  I had to change the Location assignment to

var Location = {"Name": "ABC", "Address": "123"};